# Subscription and Node action

Tags: webforms, notifications, rules

I am using Drupal 7. And i am quite new.

I want to develop a system in website where an Event is declared by the Administrator. (Event is a custom event type - or i can use any existing one if needed).  The event has a field (variable number of) subscribers to it.

If a user want to subscribe to event he/she can fill in a web form. Alternatively Subscription can be done by having a button (if such a thing is possible on node).

The problem is, usually such triggers help send an email post this. However, i want that once such an event happens, i want to modify the target node and append the current user_reference in the list of subscribers in the node.

So basically, when a user subscribes the page, the system modifies the node to append the name of such a user in the subscriber's list.

Is such a thing possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers -

Drupal 6: Use [Signup](http://www.drupal.org/project/signup)

Drupal 7: Use [Entity Registrations](http://drupal.org/project/registration)

Both of these modules do pretty much exactly what you want on both counts.

Comment: +1 and thanks a lot. This worked like a charm! I posted this long back with no hope to get answer. In the process i had also used Webforms. Webforms also works extremely well. However, for every new *node* the same webform was required to get repeated (essentially no pre-sets). Thanks a great deal!!!